# Jenkins does not wait for docker exec command to complete

Tags: docker, jenkins

Here's the situation:

I have a docker container (jenkins). I've mounted the sockets to my container so that I can perform docker commands inside my jenkins container.

Manually, everything works in the container. However, when Jenkins executes the job, it doesn't "wait" for the `docker exec` command to run to completion.

Below, is an extract from the Jenkinsfile. The short-lived `printenv` command runs correctly, and prints the environment variables. The next command (python) just gets run and then Jenkins moves on immediately, not waiting for completion. The Jenkins agent (slave) is running on an Ubuntu image. Running all these commands outside Jenkins work as expected.

```
echo "Running the app docker container in detached tty mode to keep it up"
docker run --detach --tty --name "${CONTAINER_NAME}" "${IMAGE_NAME}"

echo "Listing environment variables"
docker exec --interactive "${CONTAINER_NAME}" bash -c "printenv"

echo "Running test coverage"
docker exec --interactive "${CONTAINER_NAME}" bash -c "python -m coverage run --source . --branch -m pytest -vs"
```

It seems maybe related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24804198/jenkins-is-not-waiting-for-docker-command-to-finish).

Please can anyone explain how to get Jenkins to wait for the `docker exec` command to complete before proceeding to the next step.

Have considered alternatives, like the Docker Pipeline Plugin, but would much prefer to use something close to what I have above where possible.

Ok, another approach, I've tried using Docker Pipeline plugin [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60293353/jenkins-docker-pipeline-plugin-not-working-when-run-inside-a-jenkins-slave-docke).

Comment: This could be solved quite easily with the Docker bindings for Jenkins Pipeline if you want to go that route instead.

Comment: @MattSchuchard - thanks for the comment - are you referring to the Docker Pipeline Plugin? Any chance you could share a link to useful reference page etc.

Comment: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/ ?

Comment: Yes that would allow you to ensure your commands within the container to complete before it exits the container, since they would exist within the block (closure? unsure about Groovy terminology here) scope.

Comment: @MattSchuchard - updated the quesion, and added a link to a new SOF question around feasibility of docker pipeline plugin. If you can take a look, and have any ideas please do share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `docker.sock` as volume mount to orchestrate containers on your host machine like this in your `docker-compose.yml`

```
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Depending on your setup you might need to run

```
chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

to get going in the first place.

This works on macOS as well as Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh. This was down to the way that I'd set up docker support on the slave container.

I'd used `socat` to provide a TCP server proxy. Instead, switched that out for a plain old `docker.sock` volume between host & container.

```
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

The very first time, I had to also sort out a permissions issue by doing (inside the container):

```
rm -Rf ~/.docker 
chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

After that, everything "just worked". Very painful experience.